# Удаливший комментарий пользователь подсвечивается как автор вопроса

Tags: дефект, дизайн, инструменты-модератора

1. При [единоличном удалении комментария тревогой](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5899/178988) пользователь, удаливший комментарий, подсвечивается как автор вопроса, хотя это не так.

   When somebody [deletes a comment by single flag](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5899/178988) that user is highlited as a question author, but he is a different user.
2. В этом случае у модераторов нет кнопки восстановления.

   It that case moderators don't have an undelete button.

Пример / Example
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/744114/178988

[image: Скриншот]

PS: Имя, удалившего комментарий пользователя, изменено (я умею html).

Comment: Как ни странно, у меня отображается именно удаливший комментарий, а не автор. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что сейчас отображается у вас?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, правильное имя, но на синем фоне, как у автора.

Comment: [Дубликат на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228973/339911)

Comment: @alexolut, да, действительно, модераторы тоже подсвечиваются.